# What is the correct orientation for CV joint cage?

Tags: nissan, cv-joint

I'm replacing a torn outer CV joint boot on a 1997 Nissan Wingroad. I removed the joint from the drive shaft and disassembled it in order to clean it out and pack it with fresh grease. I made a mental note of which way around the cage goes but it's been a few days since I started the job and I'm now unsure of the correct orientation. One edge is flat and the other is beveled (see photos). Can anyone tell me which side should be facing out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normally the beveled side is facing out to allow more space for the driveshaft.
In such cases I search for the part in the aftermarket catalogues and look for a drawing.

Comment: @Martin, I looked up a replacement part the other day as I was thinking about replacing it with a new one. Photos of the part on the website aren't all that clear. However, I did another search today and although it's not the exact same part, [this one](https://www.repco.co.nz/medias/A1050870.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wxMDAxNDl8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xzeXMtbWFzdGVyL2ltYWdlcy9oODkvaGZlLzk0MjUzNzU1NTk3MTAvQTEwNTA4NzAuanBnfGNmYmZiY2EyNjJjYzRkNWNkYWQ4ZDcwZGRiMjliYTk1MWY0MmY5NGRkOThkYmM5NzgwYzQ4YTAyYzU5YTEwYzQ) clearly shows the beveled side facing out which confirms what you said.

Comment: As for drawings, I wasn't able to find any that showed the part in enough detail although I think it's safe to conclude the beveled side faces out.